# How can I write a Oracle SQL query to extract the count of all orders 4 weeks before the last order?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to extract all order 4 weeks before the last order. I have 3 tables Customer, Order and Date | I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(FO.EMAIL) AS EMAIL, 
count(FOI.ORDER_ID),
LAST_VALUE(D.DAY_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY LOWER(C.EMAIL) ORDER BY D.DAY_DATE DESC, FOI.ORDER_ID ASC) AS LatOrderDate 
FROM MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_FACT_ORDER_ITEMS FOI LEFT OUTER JOIN MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_DIM_DAY D ON FOI.ORDER_DATE_SKEY = D.DAY_SKEY LEFT OUTER JOIN MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_DIM_CUSTOMER C ON FOI.CUSTOMER_SKEY = C.CUSTOMER_SKEY WHERE DATEADD(week,-4,lastorderDate) 
group by EMAIL;
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result.

Comment: This is my sample query. I am new to the partition by function and I think i am missing something.

Comment: Edit your answer and paste the date query in it along with some test data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use window a function:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by customer
                      order by date
                      range between interval '4' weeks preceding and interval '1' second preceding
                     ) as num_orders_prev_4_weeks
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I applied the above to my query and I get a missing or invalid datetime field error. Please see my query below and let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: select lower(C.EMAIL) AS Email,
       count(FOI.ORDER_ID ) over (partition by Lower(C.EMAIL)
                      order by D.DAY_DATE
                      range between interval '4' weeks preceding and '1' second preceding
                     ) as orders_prev_4_weeks
From
MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_FACT_ORDER_ITEMS FOI Left Outer Join MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_DIM_DAY D On FOI.ORDER_DATE_SKEY = D.DAY_SKEY Left Outer Join MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_DIM_CUSTOMER C On FOI.CUSTOMER_SKEY = C.CUSTOMER_SKEY

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so can have both partition by and group by in the same query unless and until you use aggregate function on analytical function. So dont use partition by inside OVER() if you are using group by.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(FO.EMAIL) AS EMAIL, count(FOI.ORDER_ID), 
LAST_VALUE(D.DAY_DATE) OVER (ORDER BY D.DAY_DATE DESC, FOI.ORDER_ID ASC) AS LatOrderDate
FROM MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_FACT_ORDER_ITEMS FOI LEFT OUTER JOIN MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_DIM_DAY D 
ON FOI.ORDER_DATE_SKEY = D.DAY_SKEY LEFT OUTER JOIN MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_DIM_CUSTOMER C 
ON FOI.CUSTOMER_SKEY = C.CUSTOMER_SKEY 
WHERE DATEADD(week,-4,lastorderDate) group by EMAIL;
```

Comment: Did not work means query executed but result is incorrect, Could you please add sample data and expected result.